# how to implement multiple javascript function in onSubmit() form

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 js function:validateDate,validateRoom,validateCardDate and validateCard

now on submit of form I want to execute all of them.OR I want to execute 2nd if 1st is true such for all. I have implement some advise like:
     return fun1() && fun2() && fun3(),
     return fun1(); fun2(),
and made wrapper function too.. but could not get success.

UPDATE:MY CODE IS:
is their any mistake in code? every attempt has been failed so far.

```
function validateDate() {
var x = document.forms["form"]["checkin"].value;
var y = document.forms["form"]["checkout"].value;

if (x == y) {
    alert("checkout date should be different from checkin");
    return false;
}else if(x > y){
  alert("checkout date should be greater");
    return false;
}else{return true;}
}

function validateRoom() {

var a = document.forms["form"]["singleroom"].value;
var b = document.forms["form"]["doubleroom"].value;
var c = document.forms["form"]["tripleroom"].value;
if (a == 0 && b==0 && c==0) {
    alert("Please select atleast one field");
    return false;
}else{return true;}
}


function validateCardDate() {
var month = document.forms["form"]["month"].value;
var year = document.forms["form"]["year"].value;
var today = new Date();


if(year < today.getFullYear()){
  alert("Card is expired");
    return false;
}else if(year == today.getFullYear()){
  if(month <= today.getMonth())
    alert("Card is expired");
      return false;
} else {return true;}
}

function validateCard() {
var cardType = document.forms["card"]["cardType"].value;
var cardNumber = document.forms["card"]["cardNumber"].value;

if(cardType == "visa"){
var cardno = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;

if(cardNumber.match(cardno))  
    {  
  return true;  
    }  
  else  
    {  
    alert("Not a valid Visa credit card number!");  
    return false;  
    }  
}else if(cardType == "americanexpress"){
var cardno = /^(?:3[47][0-9]{13})$/;

if(cardNumber.match(cardno))  
    {  
  return true;  
    }  
  else  
    {  
    alert("Not a valid Amercican Express credit card number!");  
    return false;  
    }  
}else if(cardType == "mastercard"){
var cardno = /^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{14})$/;

if(cardNumber.match(cardno))  
    {  
  return true;  
    }  
  else  
    {  
    alert("Not a valid mastercard credit card number!");  
    return false;  
    }  
}
else if(cardType == "jcb"){
var cardno = /^(?:(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/;

if(cardNumber.match(cardno))  
    {  
  return true;  
    }  
  else  
    {  
    alert("Not a valid JCB credit card number!");  
    return false;  
    }  
 }

 }
```

Comment: show us your attempts please. What did you try so far?

Comment: Hello Shushan and welcome to SO! I would like to advise you some SO documentation that may help you in asking a better qestion. For instance you may be interested about the [topics we discuss here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [the way to ask a 'good' question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the way to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you find it useful, you can still edit your question.

Comment: chaining with the && operator is the way to go. the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function which has all those four functions inside it

Example:

```
function ParentFunction() {
    validateDate()
    validateRoom()
    validateCardDate()
    validateCard()
}
```

An onSubmit call the `ParentFunction()`. This way you can even use arguments and decision controls to run those functions in any sequence you like.

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
var validateDate = function () {
    // Statements
    return true // if conditions are what you want
}
var validateRoom = function () {
    // Statements
    return true // if conditions are what you want
}
var validateCardDate = function () {
    // Statements
    return true // if conditions are what you want
}
var validateCard = function () {
    // Statements
    return true // if conditions are what you want
}
function ParentFunction() {
    if (validateDate() == true) {
        if (validateRoom() == true) {
            if (validateCardDate() == true) {
                if (validateCard() == true) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it only execute first function i.e only validateDate() will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
if (func1()){
  if(func2()){
    if(func3()){
      return func4()
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }else{
    return false
  }
}else{
 return false
}
```

Every functions func1...func4 should be return a false or true value.

Comment: it is very hard and unmanage way. it will create more problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
function main(){
//functions to exexute.
}
```

Then do:

```
onsubmit="main()"
```

If you want to execute the second if the first is true then

- The first function must return true

  if(main()){if(//otherfunction){}}

Comment: it is very hard and unmanage way. it will create more problem.